# Android Weight Not Working

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a textview and edittext in a linear layout.  Neither view shows up at all if done the way I've seen every example of using weight to set width as a percentage of parent that I can find.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/custLabel"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight=".35"
  android:layout_width="0dip"  
  android:text="Name"/>
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/customer"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight=".65"
  android:layout_width="0dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am using mono droid in visual studio.  Debugging directly to device.

Comment: Your `LinearLayout` has a vertical orientation. Set your `layout_width to `"wrap_content"` and `layout_height` to `0dp` for your `TextView` and `EditText`. You're doing it the wrong way around.

Comment: @MisterSquonk   It is the first time I typed fasted than some of gurus :-)

Comment: @Gangnus: Yes, you beat me to it. I up-voted your answer. :-)

Comment: @MisterSquonk *Gangnus is bowing*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the orientation of the Layout. You have it vertical and put things there, weighting width!

Comment: Three days ago I wasted 3 hours because of the wrong LinearLayout orientation :-)